# Form Submit Error Page and Success Page

Tags: simple-search

Does anyone no how to style the standard EE success/error page that appears after submitting a simple form? It would be nice not to have this default page and style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go to CP -> Design -> Message Pages -> User Messages

Here you can see the User Message template and can style accordingly.